# Can I legally contract with a foreign person to do work in the United States

Tags: contracting

I want to invite a foreign person to come to the United States to do certain projects for me without going through a HB1 process.  Can this be done legally if the project takes less than 90 days?

Comment: Despite the use of the word "legally" in the question, this isn't really asking for legal advice, just visa information.

Answer (score 2):

**No**.  Any sort of work for remuneration, for any duration in the United States, [requires a temporary work visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/employment/temporary.html).  On a B-1 (business) or B-1/2 (business/tourism) visa, you can only legally:

> Negotiate and sign contracts
>
> Purchase supplies or materials
>
> Hold business meetings or attend/exhibit at a convention
>
> Settle an estate
>
> Sit different types of exams and tests held inside the United States

Now there are a [number of exceptions](http://www.usvisalawyers.co.uk/article15.htm), but these are for very specific purposes generally involving employees of foreign companies sent to the US to install/service/consult and would most likely not apply to "doing certain projects".